# value of type '1-dimensional array of Byte' cannot be converted to integer, any ideas?

Tags: vb.net, pointers, readprocessmemory

I have used the following code to read a memory address from a pointer and offset previously however, Now I've come to use it again and can't figure out how I got it working last time, I'm receiving the error "value of type '1-dimensional array of Byte' cannot be converted to integer" highlighting the BytesAtAddress variable in the ReadProcessMemory calls.

I've been stuck on this for about 25 minutes can anyone point out to me what is wrong as i'm sure it's simple.

Thanks!

```
Public Shared Function ReadPointerFromMemory(ByVal BaseAddress As Integer, ByVal PointerOffset As Integer, ByVal BytesToRead As Integer, ByVal pHandle As IntPtr) As Integer
    Dim BytesAtAddress As Byte() = New Byte(BytesToRead - 1) {}
    Dim BytesRead As Integer
    Dim MemoryBase As Integer
    Dim ReturnVal As Integer
    ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, CType(BaseAddress, IntPtr), BytesAtAddress, BytesToRead, BytesRead)
    MemoryBase = BitConverter.ToInt32(BytesAtAddress, 0)
    MemoryBase += PointerOffset
    ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, CType(MemoryBase, IntPtr), BytesAtAddress, BytesToRead, BytesRead)
    ReturnVal = BitConverter.ToInt32(BytesAtAddress, 0)
    Return ReturnVal
End Function
```

Comment: Was Option Strict not on the last time you used it?

Comment: It's off at the minute. This is annoying me ;(

Comment: Can you show the declaration of the ReadProcessMemory method?

Comment: Thank you guys, that was it, i figured it out just now too I was using the wrong one! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I assume your using `ReadProcessMemory` from : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms886794.aspx as reference.

```
BOOL ReadProcessMemory( 
  HANDLE hProcess, 
  LPCVOID lpBaseAddress, 
  LPVOID lpBuffer, 
  DWORD nSize, 
  LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesRead 
);
```

So and on accord with the error what you need is a pointer on the buffer `BytesAtAddress` not the array itself. You may also change `MemoryBase As Integer` to `MemoryBase As IntPtr` and `ReturnVal As Integer` to `ReturnVal As IntPtr`. Or even better pass all needed variables ByRef instead of ByVal to your function.